# How to make SVG clickable in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have an SVG image to and I want to make that clickable in android and get the details of selected path.

I have used a library but my application crashes.
[Zoomable SVG with clickable areas - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211780/zoomable-svg-with-clickable-areas-android)

Comment: Post your code and the crash logs

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set an OnClickListener on the view containing the SVG in your activity of fragment

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener